# Why two DataFrames get linked when using `=` with them?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am have a very weird problem with my code. After saving the DataFrame data in another variable, and changing the temporary one, the first one gets also updated. Example :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Test'] = [1, 2, 3]

temp = pd.DataFrame()
temp = df

temp['New Column'] = [2, 3, 4]

print(df)
```

Results :

```
   Test  New Column
0     1           2
1     2           3
2     3           4
```

Am I missing something here ?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: you can use temp=df.copy() if you need a seperate copy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
temp = df
```

doesn't create a copy of `df`, but instead makes `temp` be just an other name for `df`. And because dataframes are mutable, the changes through one name are reflected on the other.